# Not Implemented (Exception from HResult: 0x8004001 (E_NOTIMPL)) (EF Power Tools Beta 2 + VS 2012))

Tags: entity-framework

When trying to generate an entity data model from by DbContext, I get a popup whet the message:

Not Implemented (Exception from HResult: 0x8004001 (E_NOTIMPL))

For other DbContext classes this message does not popup.

I'm using VS 2012 ultimate and Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2.

Any suggestions about what is going on.

Thanks in advance,
Merijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [EF Power Tools Beta 3 released today](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/01/30/ef-power-tools-beta-3-available.aspx). It contains a number of fixes for issues of this kind.

Comment: Unfortunately, in another dbcontext class I not get the message "a constructive type deriving from dbcontext could not be found in the selected file.". However, this file does contain a public class that derives from dbcontext, _and_, it has a public parameter-less constructor.